# Hermes Cofiguration with SoapUI 5.0.0

Tags: jms, soapui

I am trying to set hermesJMS config file under prefernces --> tools and have given the whole path of hermes-config.xml file like this `c:\..\..\hermes-config.xml` and saved the preferences. But when I am trying to open HermesJMS under tools from soapUI 5.0.0 it complains about setting the prefernces, which I've already set. I also tried restarting soapUI but doesnt work. Any help is appreciated. HermesJMS was installed when I installed soapui 5.0.0. I didnt install it separately. Thanks.

Comment: Anyone on this pls. I am still not able to resolve this.

Comment: Got it working, we've to give path upto hermesJMS folder and not to hermes-config.xml file for soapUI 5.0.0 (hermes installed with soapUI). Thanks.

Comment: For the benefit of others, you are able to answer your own question and accept your own answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working, we've to give path upto hermesJMS folder and not to hermes-config.xml file for soapUI 5.0.0 (hermes installed with soapUI). Thanks

Comment: this is indeed the case.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue on latest version 5.0 - Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Just that it may be helpful for others I am sharing the work around. Most likely, it was a memory issue.

By default, the location is *C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.0.0\hermesJMS* what you mentioned above. So, no need to change it.

One can go hermes.bat file at location *C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.0.0\hermesJMS\bin* and edit last line -XX:NewSize=256m **-Xmx512m** to -XX:NewSize=256m **-Xmx1024m**.